Is there only one universe? Does a multiverse exist?
Is there only one universe, or does a multiverse exist? What evidence or theories in physics support the idea of multiple universes, and how does this concept challenge our understanding of reality?

Are you asking this question just for the sake of asking? If you want from Hindu perspective answer is there in the feed of this website today. If you want from physics perspective then it is off topic
